# Android - RecyclerView items aren't visible after orientation change

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-orientation, android-flexboxlayout, conductor

I'm using in my app the [Conductor framework](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/Conductor).

The app in general is fixed in **portrait** state, but I have 2 `Controllers` that use `ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_FULL_SENSOR` and respond to device orientation changes

- `Controller` **A** - shows a summary of images taken
- `Controller` **B** - is the camera interaction

so when **A** is launched, it immediately launches **B** and shows the summary after images are taken.

**A** holds a `RecyclerView` that uses `FlexboxLayoutManager` (when I tried replacing the layout manager w/ a simple `LinearLayoutManager` nothing changed)

I have 3 flows that work fine:

1. The device in held in **Portrait** -> **A** is launched -> **B** is launched -> images are taken -> **B** is closed -> the images are **Shown** in **A**
2. The device in held in **Landscape** -> **A** is launched -> **B** is launched -> images are taken -> **B** is closed -> the images are **Shown** in **A**
3. The device in held in **Portrait** -> **A** is launched -> **B** is launched -> device orientation **changes to Landscape** -> images are taken -> orientation **changes to Portrait**-> **B** is closed -> the images are **Shown** in **A**

However this scenario fails:

The device in held in **Portrait** -> **A** is launched -> **B** is launched -> device orientation **changes to Landscape** -> images are taken -> **B** is closed -> the images are **NOT** shown in **A**

In all the flows I see that the `adapter` is aware of the new items, and `getItemViewType`, `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` are called with the correct positions

The flow that fails is actually that one that seems most natural to me as a user :(

- Does anyone have any idea what is going on?
- Can you suggest additional directions for investigation?

**UPDATE:**

- The recycler view was defined with `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`
- Changing to `android:layout_height="match_parent"` while working with `LinearLayoutManager` works (looks ugly)
- Changing it back to `FlexboxLayoutManager` fails all the flows that worked before

So I'm taking a look now at `FlexboxLayoutManager` to see if I can fix this easily - I don't think that a recycler view is actually needed in my flow

Comment: it will be helpful if you could share some code of your adapter and at least how do you deal with the configuration change

Comment: I think RecyclerVIew should always be defined with android:layout_height="match_parent"
I think you should show us the layout of the item so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution was just changing the `RecyclerView` from `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`.

In the update above I said that it still doesn't work with `FlexboxLayoutManager`, but the problem was on my end (too commenting out and in of code).

The original code wasn't written by me, so I'm not sure why `wrap_content` was used